# Show button onClick event of another button

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I need to show status after the onClick event of a button. But I want the shown button to be on another page. Is this possible?

For example, one button on my Investigation page shows the patient status for a user. If I click that button, the investigation status should be Pending and a user list should display in front of that particular patient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using jquery
  Html

```
 <button id="first-button" type="button" class="btn"> first button </button>
 <button id="second-button" type="button" class="btn hide"> Pending </button>
```

Script

```
 $("#first-button").click(function(){
    ev.preventDefault();    
    $('#second-button').removeClass('hide');
    $('#first-button').addClass('hide');
  });
```

OR
 In php

```
<?php 
  if($pedding)
  {
    echo '<button id="pending" type="button" class="btn">Pending</button>';
  }
  else
  {
    echo '<button id="status" type="button" class="btn">Status</button>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: also add a css <style> .hide{display:none;}</style>

Comment: @Komal Thanks, but I want to show or hide button on another page.

Comment: If you want to show on another page then simply check the status in php and if you want to same page without reloading your page then use javascript

Comment: Instead of adding / removing a class you could just use .show() and .hide() that comes with Jquery, or use .toggle() which will auto switch between the two.